# finding the area between two curves using two parts

Tags: calculus

I think I have this correct, but would like to check my concepts are sound because this needed two integrations.

[image]

So, it looks to me like this would best be done by a dy problem, divided into two parts as follows: {in this question I will finally figure out how to write integrals with bounds in Mathjax}

$A=\int_0^1 y^\frac14 dy + \int_1^e (1-ln y) dy$

The other issue with this answer, although intuitively correct, is that we have not yet learned integration by parts.  So, integrating $ln y$ was on my own from the internet.

Is the integral for the area set up correctly?

Comment: It's correct, but why not do the integral w.r.t. $x$ instead? Then you only need to compute $$\int_0^1 (e^x-x^4)~dx.$$ You don't need integration by parts here.

Comment: I didn't see it that way at first.  Now I do

Comment: I computed the answer both ways and didn't get the same answer.  Maybe I did the integration by parts incorrectly.

Comment: You should get the same answer, note that $$\int_1^e (1-\ln(y))~dx=[2y-y\ln(y)]_1^e=(2e-e)-2=e-2,$$ and $$\int_0^1 (e^x-x^4)~dx=e-6/5.$$